# SSRS Fill Color Expression based on Multiple Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a table in an SSRS report that I am trying to set the fill color for one of the columns based on if the value contained in the cell falls within a couple of user entered parameters.

The report allows the user to enter a minimum value and a maximum value but neither is required.

So for example a user could enter a minimum value of 5 with no max value, a max value of 5 with no minimum value, or a min and max value.

With this information entered I need to set the fill color for the corresponding cell  for that input to be red if the value returned is less than the minimum value entered or more than the maximum value entered.

The expression I am currently using works when both a min and max value are entered but not when only a minimum value is entered.

This is the expression I am using at the moment. I get the feeling I am making this harder on myself than it needs to be but I am not quite sure what else to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
IIF(Parameters!YSMin.Value<>"" AND Parameters!YSMax.Value <>"", 
IIF(Fields!Yield_Strength.Value<Parameters!YSMin.Value OR Fields!Yield_Strength.Value>Parameters!YSMax.Value,"Red","Transparent"),
IIF(Parameters!YSMin.Value<>"" AND Parameters!YSMax.Value ="",
IIF(Fields!Yield_Strength.Value<Parameters!YSMin.Value,"Red","Transparent"),"Transparent"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your logic essentially returns the same condition to being over the `max` or under the `min` where available, you can simplify your conditional logic here with a `switch` expression that simply checks for either situation.  There is no need to check for all the various combinations as in your `iif` statements.

Put simply, if either "there is a min and we are under it" or "there is a max and we are over it" are true the background is `Red`, otherwise leave it transparent, so:

```
=switch(not isnothing(Parameters!YSMin.Value) and Fields!Yield_Strength.Value < Parameters!YSMin.Value, "Red"
       ,not isnothing(Parameters!YSMax.Value) and Fields!Yield_Strength.Value > Parameters!YSMax.Value, "Red"
       ,True,"Transparent"
       )
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still only works when a value is entered for both the min and max values not either or.

Comment: Neither comparison is checking both parameters in this expression, so whether both are filled in or not shouldn't matter.  Can you update your answer with screenshots of the error or undesired behaviour you are seeing?

Comment: I apologize this works the problem was I had the parameters set up as text inputs and not floats which was causing issues with the comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored this to use SWITCH as I find it simpler to understand.

Try this (untested)

```
=SWITCH(
    NOT(IsNothing(Parameters!YSMin.Value)) AND Fields!Yield_Strength.Value < Parameters!YSMin.Value, "Red",
    NOT(IsNothing(Parameters!YSMax.Value)) AND Fields!Yield_Strength.Value > Parameters!YSMax.Value, "Red",
    True, Nothing
)
```

Comment: I've just seen iamdave's answer which is virtually identical except for the last line. You need pairs of values for SWITCH so the final 'True' acts like an else. If this does not work, please show a screen shot of how your parmeters are setup (allow NULL, allow blanks etc) as this will have a bearing

Comment: Ooops, yes that final `True` is required!

Comment: I apologize this works the problem was I had the parameters set up as text inputs and not floats which was causing issues with the comparisons.